# php ajax shoutbox issues

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, captcha

I am trying to implement this shoutbox

http://shoutbox.insanityville.com/

but there are a few issues and modifications I would like to make

issue - when a user forgets to fill a field an error message is displayed and all fields are cleared.

**how can I modify it to clear the fields only on success?**

modification

**how can I make the new messages slide in like in this example?**

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/11/insert-delete-with-jquery-and-ajax.html

modification

**How can I add a captcha?**

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the success handler is emptying the input fields, so this would need to be moved to after the logic which determines whether there was an error in the response:

```
success: function(xml){
    $('#shoutNickname').val('');
    $('#shoutMessage').val('');
    etc...
```

Needs to go

```
if($('error', xml).text()) {
 $('#shoutStatus').empty().removeClass().addClass('shoutError').html($('error', xml).text());
} else {
 /** HERE! **/
 $('#shoutStatus').empty().removeClass().addClass('shoutStatus').html($('status', xml).text());
}
```

To implement the slideDown effect, you should check out the [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown) docs

To implement the CAPTCHA, I would recommend [securimage](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/). It's simple to implement, just takes a little server side validation and an input box on the front-end. You then just need to modify the `data` object being passed to $.ajax() to include the additional input value and make sure the server-side validation is updated to include a proper error response when validation fails.